# Shortening down this specific code

Tags: python, code-complexity

I have been studying Python for a couple of weeks now, and just after easter,  will be having a controlled assesment that will count towards my GCSE grade, for which I will be also marked for the criteria of something like the lentgh of my code.

The question was: Write a Python program that asks the user for a word, then calculates the prints the vowel value of the word entered.

What I want to know:

> Is there anyway of shortening down this code?

And also:

> How can the program be executed without printing out the "word" variable?

Above I have been given a rubric that I used in the code (in the control flow part).

```
score = 0

word = str(input("Input a word: "))

c = 0
for letter in word:
        print(word[c])
        c = c + 1
        if letter == "a":
                score = score + 5
        if letter == "e":
                score = score + 4
        if letter == "i":
                score = score + 3
        if letter == "o":
                score = score + 2
        if letter == "u":
                score = score + 1

print("\nThe score for your word is: " + score)
```

Comment: Note that Python has a `+=` operator. You could write `score = score + 2` as `score += 2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sum` and a `dict`, storing vowels as keys and the associated value as the values:

```
word = input("Input a word: ")

values = {"a":5,"e":4,"i":3,"o":2,"u":1}
print(sum(values.get(ch,0) for ch in word))
```

`values.get(ch,0)` will return `0` as a default value if the `ch` which is each char in  the word is not a vowel therefore not in our dict.

`sum(values.get(ch,0) for ch in word)` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) where the variables are  *evaluated lazily when the **next**() method is called for generator object*

In relation to your own code you should use if/elif's. A character can only have one value, if's are always evaluated but elif's are only evaluated if the previous statement evaluates to False:

```
score = 0
 # already a str in python3 use raw_input in python2
word = input("Input a word: ")

for letter in word:
        if letter == "a":
            score += 5 # augmented assignment same as score = score + 5
        elif letter == "e":
            score += 4
        elif letter == "i":
            score += 3
        elif letter == "o":
            score += 2
        elif letter == "u":
            score += 1
```

Comment: Thanks man, but I guess I'll have to go with the second version because my teacher doesn't expect me to know about dictionaries yet (although I already do because I did some early research) and if I was going to use it, She probably would of said that I have to redo because it's "too advanced" and I "copied" it from the internet, which is "bad for my controlled assesment" as I won't be  able to understand it.

Comment: No prob, it is good to understand the difference between if's and elif's anyway, there are times you want the next statement checked regardless and vise versa so understanding the difference between the two is important.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code:

```
word = input("Input a word: ")

values = {"a":5,"e":4,"i":3,"o":2,"u":1}
score = sum(values[let] for let in word if let in values)

print("\nThe score for your word is: " + score)
```